# Updating string value in MongoDB Collection

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a string variable in my collection. I'm using the .update method.

```
Invoice.update({_id: "5c8c170cc96b8835c06fb54f"}, {$set: {isPaid: "True"}});
```

Upon running the value will not change in my database.

```
{"_id":"5c8c170cc96b8835c06fb54f","item":"Coffee","date":"03/15/2019","notes":"1 cup","amount":"0.75","owed":"0.75","isPaid":"False","invoice_customer":"Name","__v":0}
```

I've tried all of the update functions that mongodb has to offer but none of them work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get a response from your update attempt?

Comment: Show the code in full context. The statement is either not executing ( lack of Promise/callback resolution) OR since you appear to be using "mongoose" your "schema" does not have `isPaid` defined at all, hence it get's removed. `mongoose.set("debug", true)` will also give you useful information on what is ( or is not ) happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try `"isPaid"` instead of `isPaid`
2. *`{new: true}` will return the updated document*

**EDIT**: @Neil Lunn `{ new: true }` is only a valid option for findOneAndUpdate() and it's variants

---

Here is the code:

```
 Invoice.update({_id: "5c8c170cc96b8835c06fb54f"}, {$set: {"isPaid": "True"}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
     if(err){
         console.log("err: " + err);
     }        
     console.log(doc);

 });
```

Comment: `{ new: true }` is not a valid option for `update()`. It only applies to `findOneAndUpdate()` and it's variants

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a few errors here

First it's `"isPaid"` and not `isPaid` 
Second, because you are searching from an `_id` it is not the value _id but objectID.
You should test with

```
Invoice.update({_id: ObjectID("5c8c170cc96b8835c06fb54f")}, {$set: {isPaid: "True"}});
```

But your need to reference ObjectID (from mongo)

Comment: Quotation on keys makes no difference at all. `isPaid` is valid JavaScript notation, as is `"isPaid"`. But as shown in the question that is "JSON serialization", for which Quotation is not *mandatory* but generally recommended, and `JSON.stringify()` ( which would be producing the output ) does this by default. Also **mongoose** ( which is what the OP is using, automatically **casts** to `ObjectId`. Also it's been aliased as `ObjectId` from `ObjectID`for a **very** long time, so you seem to be copying from a very old post